# Is "aggregate percentage" still a valid term in ecology?

Tags: ecology, terminology, statistics, diet, community-ecology

[Martin et al. 1946](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3795806) define "aggregate percentage" as a metric that describes the mean percentage contribution of a group to the total mass/abundance of all samples. The metric is useful in datasets that are plagued by outliers and non-normality, something that is a commonplace with most ecological community and diet studies in my experience. Aggregate percentage is calculated as follows:

$AP_i = \frac{100\%}{N_y} \times \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N}(\frac{a_{ij}}{\sum a_j})$

Where i is the i$^{th}$ taxon, j the j$^{th}$ sample, N total number of samples, a$_{ij}$ the abundance or mass of i$^{th}$ taxon in j$^{th}$ sample, and $\sum a_j$ the summed abundance or mass of all taxa in j$^{th}$ sample.

Martin et al. 1946 illustrate this as follows:

[image]

I am sure that "aggregate percentage" is a standard method in ecology, but I cannot find many studies using this term by googling. Probably the method has synonyms and there might be a more accepted term for the method nowadays. **My question is what is the valid term to use for the method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula of "aggregate percentage" that you show is just the arithmetic mean of percentages, and I suspect that no special term is used in most studies that use mean percentages as a measure of e.g. prey composition in a certain predator (as seems to be the case in your example).

When searching for studies I think you will have more luck with using "*mean prey percentages*", "*prey percentages*" or "*mean percentage composition*". For instance, see [Shoup & Lane (2015)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/02755947.2015.1067260) which includes the text (with my emphasis):

> Results of regressions correlating Secchi depth (mm) with **prey percentages** by weight in the stomach contents of Largemouth Bass sampled from Boomer.

Also ([Ahlbeck et al, 2012](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/full/10.1139/f2012-051?mobileUi=0&#.Vs7vX-btvJU)):

> For each of the 25 individuals in each size class, the diet composition was calculated as the mass percentages of different prey, and then the **average mass percentages** were calculated for the size class.
>   [...]
>   **prey percentages** were first calculated for each fish separately and then averaged over all individuals in the sample (Hyslop 1980).

Finally, [Ledger & Hildrew (2008)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2427.2001.00764.x/full):

> **Mean percentage composition** (food category area as percentage total particle area) of faecal pellets of N. pictetii nymphs fed biofilm from four acid streams and four circumneutral streams.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It certainly seems that there is no standardized name for this method (which is just a mean of percentages, as you say). I suppose I was thinking about "frequency of occurrence", also a simple method that had several names until people settled to that term. I'll wait for some days and accept this answer unless someone comes up with a better one.

Comment: @Mikko I agree that it's not entirely obvious, and people come up with all sorts of terms for basically the same thing (which can be a big problem). Personally, I hadn't heard of "aggregate percentage" before, and my main point is that most that use it as a statistic are probably not calling it that (or any other specific term necessarily).